On the inverse of LCUs for Hamiltonian simulation
Let $H = \sum_j \alpha_j U_j$ be a linear combination of unitaries (LCU) representation for a Hamiltonian that we wish to simulate (i.e., construct a circuit approximating $e^{iHt}$). The standard technique is to use the LCU technique involving PREP and SELECT oracles, which generates a block encoding
$$B = \begin{bmatrix}H/\|\alpha\|_1 & X\\Y & Z\end{bmatrix}.$$
$X,Y,Z$ are matrices in the other blocks that we don't care about. Then we use quantum signal processing (QSP) to construct a circuit consisting of interleaved applications of $B$, $B^\dagger$, and controlled $z$-rotations which is some $\varepsilon$ close to $e^{iHt}$, as desired.
My question is whether the explicit circuit for $B^\dagger$ is necessary for the QSP to succeed? To avoid triviality, suppose that the $U_j$'s are not self-inverse (although I recognize that this is typically the case, since most applications use a Pauli decomposition for the LCU). Then inverting the SELECT oracle, we get
$$B^\dagger = \begin{bmatrix}H^\dagger/\|\alpha\|_1 & Y^\dagger\\X^\dagger & Z^\dagger\end{bmatrix} \neq B.$$
But since obviously $H = H^\dagger$, using $B$ instead of $B^\dagger$ is still correct in the block that we care about. Intuitively, I would expect this to mean that there is no need to explicitly construct $B^\dagger$, as $B$ serves its same purpose as far as the block encoding goes. On the other hand, would the fact that $BB \neq I$ cause some complications?
